# Selenium, switch between headless and non headless

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I'm trying to find information on how to use selenium in a headless situation.

HTMLUnitDriver did not work for me, so I'm trying to use PhantomJSDriver();

Firefox doesnt' seem to do headless.

So my question is, is phantom only headless? Is there any way to switch headless off and test it as a normal browser?

If not, how do I actually know that my script is working properly? For instance, if I test it in firefox, can I assume my script will just "work" exactly the same way in phantom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whole idea of PhantomJS is to test your code without actually rendering page. It saves some time. There is no way to run tests in "normal" mode case we're talking about PhantomJS, however you have opportunity to take screenshots on test failure, PhantomJS will render whole page for you in this case.

As of Firefox - you can run it in headless mode when using Linux and virtual displays.
Also, please be aware of the fact that PhantomJS is using different engine, so you may have different results.